# How to create a MacOS app bundle with cmake

Tags: macos, cmake, bundle

This can be considered as a follow-up to [CMake MacOS X bundle with BundleUtiliies for Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612687/cmake-macos-x-bundle-with-bundleutiliies-for-qt-application)

I want to create a MACOS bundle on CI which can be used by users for an open source project.

What I have:

- Main executable
- Updater executable
- icon file
- helper script calling updater then main
- data files in a folder (translations etc, some generated at build time)
- plugin shared libs

What I've done so far:

- add `MACOSX_BUNDLE` to the executable
- add icon to its sources and to `RESOURCE` property
- set `MACOSX_BUNDLE_*` properties
- install everything in a cross-platform way (regular `install(TARGETS` calls and `install(FILES` for the resources)

But now I'm stuck on how to get those into the bundle w/o to much manual work.

From the linked question I got something like this:

```
set(APPS "\$ENV{DESTDIR}\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${PROJECT_NAME}.app")
set(LIBS )
set(DIRS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
# Path used for searching by FIND_XXX(), with appropriate suffixes added
if(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
        foreach(dir ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
                list(APPEND DIRS "${dir}/bin" "${dir}/lib")
        endforeach()
endif()
install(CODE "include(BundleUtilities)
  fixup_bundle(\"${APPS}\" \"${LIBS}\" \"${DIRS}\")")
```

But:

- Why do I need to pass the `*.app` path manually? CMake does already know it, doesn't it?
- `LIBS` should contain my plugins, shouldn't it? But what? Paths? Target names?
- `DIRS` is also a mystery to me. No documentation even in CMake 3.12 (I'm still using 2.8.12 though :( )
- How to add my generated and regular data files? Probably same or similar to the icon? But what about the generated ones?

Help, pointers to examples, full CMakeLists doing that etc. very welcome.

Note: I'm cross-compiling from linux on the CI and NOT using Qt so e.g. `macdeployqt` or so is out of question.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  If you could post a solution, that would be useful.

Comment: Here is my CMakeList for a macOS program that builds into an app bundle. https://gist.github.com/minorsecond/cd23af812afffb656c8d7d413ed9792a

Answer (score 13):

Just got stuck on the same issue and google brought me here.

This worked for me:

```
set(CUR_TARGET myappname)
add_executable(${CUR_TARGET} MACOSX_BUNDLE ${MY_SRC})            
set_target_properties(${CUR_TARGET} PROPERTIES
    BUNDLE True
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.domain.style.identifier.${CUR_TARGET}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME ${CUR_TARGET}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION "0.1"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING "0.1"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/customtemplate.plist.in
)
```

The file customtemplate.plist.in is based on the cmake template from the cmake dir subfolder at your_cmake_install_dir/share/cmake/Modules/MacOSXBundleInfo.plist.in

Comment: It is also necessary to add a 'BUNDLE DESTINATION' to the INSTALL rule.  For example:

INSTALL( TARGETS ${CUR_TARGET} 
                 BUNDLE DESTINATION /path/to/bundle